# Specify an array variable in the path for opening a new file

Tags: perl, filehandle

Although I found many posts on how to open a file in a for loop in perl, I am having a specific issue in creating a file within a directory ( which is also the array variable)-

I am opening a file using

```
foreach my $dir (@listofdirs) {

open (my $OUTFILE, '>', "$dir/$dir.txt") or die "$!";
```

, this does not create a file and gives me an error No such file or directory.

If i just use open `(my $OUTFILE, '>', "$dir.txt") or die;`  It works and creates a file under main directory from where I execute the script.

**How can I control/specify the path so that it opens a file inside each $dir variable (directory)?** I am sorry if this has been addressed earlier, but I am not sure what is the right way to specify the path for the new files.

**Edit -**

**Can I change directory where the file is being created inside the loop and assign it the $dir variable value everytime?**

Comment: What error do you receive? What is the value of `$dir`?

Comment: `or die;` isn't going to tell you what went wrong. You *could* add `or die "Failed to open $dir/$dir.txt: $!"` to every `open` call... or you can remove the `or die` and instead add `use autodie` at the top of your program. Now if file functions like `open` fail they will automatically die with a descriptive error message.

Comment: value of $dir would be a directory like folder1, folder2 etc that is getting populated from listofdirs - which has list of many such folders in it.  The error I get is Died at this `open (my $OUTFILE, '>', "$dir/$dir.txt")` line

Comment: @AnkP Like Schwern mentioned, you need to either `use autodie;` to get the real error message or `open (my $OUTFILE, '>', "$dir/$dir.txt") or die "$!";`

Comment: the task is to read each directory name from the list of directories and create a file inside that directory or $dir variable. Right now my script creates all files under the directory which has the list of directories.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it and I am getting error - `No such file or directory at test.pl line 19`, which is the open file file.

Comment: Do those directories exist? Mind the error message: _No such file **or directory** ..._

Comment: Hi @PerlDog, yes the directories did exist, but I guess it was not working since I was using /$dir/$dir.txt to create a new file. I changed that to $dir/List.txt and it works well now.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Sorry for the noise. @Schwern explained it very good in his answer.

Comment: I have another issue though. I am populating this listofdirectories using File::Find::Rule on my root directory, but it is reading in my root directory as well in the array, is there anyway I can neglect the main directory and only read in subdirectories? I see this question is very different from my psot so will post it as a different question.

Comment: @AnkP You may wish to look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule and https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing your error message, I have a pretty good idea what's wrong.

```
foreach my $dir (@listofdirs) {
    open (my $OUTFILE, '>', "$dir/$dir.txt") or die; 
    ...
}
```

I'm going to guess `@listofdirs` contains things like `/foo/bar` or `foo/bar/baz/` and thus `"$dir/$dir.txt"` will create some funny filepaths.

```
$dir                      "$dir/$dir.txt"
/foo/bar                  /foo/bar//foo/bar.txt
foo/bar/                  foo/bar//foo/bar/.txt
foo/                      foo//foo/.txt
```

Most of these aren't going to work for various reasons.  `/foo/bar//foo/bar.txt` will require that the directory `/foo/bar/foo/` already exists.  `foo/bar//foo/bar/.txt` is an invalid path.

`"$dir/$dir.txt"` is a funny construct anyway.  Are you sure that's what you meant to do?

---

To figure out what's gone wrong you can add an some information to your error message.  The traditional way is to write it all out long hand on every `open` call.

```
foreach my $dir (@listofdirs) {
    open (my $OUTFILE, '>', "$dir/$dir.txt")
        or die "Can't open '$dir/$dir.txt': $!";
    ...
}
```

Now you'll see what it tried to open, and why it failed (contained in [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)).  This rapidly gets tiresome and inconsistent, so it's better to let [`autodie`](http://metacpan.org/pod/autodie) do it for you.

```
# at the top of your code along with things like "use strict"
use autodie;

...

foreach my $dir (@listofdirs) {
    open (my $OUTFILE, '>', "$dir/$dir.txt");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Schwern, you were right, I am getting error that no such file or directory exist. My goal is to create a file inside each directory listed in the array, as I mentioned my command is creating new files in the main directory as I am not able to direct the path correctly!